# java r interfaceの有効桁数

Tags: java, r

【質問】
java r interface（JRI）を使用して、Rの結果を取得しています。
JRIで返す桁数とRのGUIで返す桁数に差異があり、どこでJRIの桁数を指定したら良いのか分かりません。
どなたかご教示お願いします。

【事象】
RのGUI
  1.getOption(digits)を実行して、デフォルトの7であることを確認。
  2.「t.test」コマンドを実行して、tが-1.234567(数字は仮)でなることを確認。
JRI
  1.evalでRのGUI1.と同じコマンドを実行して、デフォルトの7であることを確認。
  2.evalでRのGUI2.と同じコマンドを実行すると、tが-1.23456789012345(数字は仮)になってしまう。
  ✳︎evalでOption(digits=1)を実行しても、上記2.と同じ結果になる。

【その他情報】
JRI-0.9.7.jar
spring boot 1.5.19
java1.8

【ソースコード】
下記イメージになります。
必要箇所だけ抜粋しています。

```java
～
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;
～


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Rengine engine = new Rengine(new String[] { "--no-save" }, false, null);

    // dataframe作成
    engine.eval("dataframe <- data.frame(\"group1\"=c(100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,136,127,128,160,158,158,159,159,158,157,156,155))");

    // ここでは7が返ってくる。
    engine.eval("getOption(\"digits\")");
    engine.eval("options(digits=5)");

    // ここでは5が返ってくる。
    engine.eval("getOption(\"digits\")");

    // ★取得結果の桁数がRGUIを実行した際と異なる。
    REXP result = engine.eval("t.test(dataframe$group1, mu=150, alternative=\"less\", data=dataframe)");
}
```

Comment: JRIの方で実際に動かしているプログラムを追記して頂くことは可能ですか？　質問文下の「編集」から追記ができます :)

Comment: プログラム追記しました。

Answer (score 0):

`options`のヘルプを見てみると

> digits: controls the number of digits to print when printing numeric values.

とあります。要するに、`options(digits)`は、数値の表示桁数を制御するものです。あくまで**表示だけ**で、内部では、十進数で15桁ほどの有効桁数で値を持っています。Rで計算をすれば、`options(digits)`の設定にかかわらず、この有効桁数全部を使って計算しています。

JNIで取ってきているのは、表示結果ではなく、数値なので、`options(digits)`の設定は全く関係ありません。

数値自体の有効桁数を短くしたいのなら、別途、自分で計算する必要があると思います。